# Exception "No view found for id" when using cardview

Tags: android, fragment, cardview

I have an error when I use `cardview` in my fragment. It shows that  illegal argument exception no view found.

> No view found for id 0x7f0d006d (com.cloudcode.didiksazali.aplikasi:id/frame) for fragment HomeFragment{1f0fd70f #1 id=0x7f0d006d home}

Code: **HomeFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not in `HomeFragment` itself. That message means that the `View` you passed the `R.id.frame` for in the `FragmentTransaction` cannot be found in the hosting component, most likely your `Activity`.

Comment: You should post your xml file. The reason can be in Xml file